# Page redirection on submit... Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I created a web application that edit a database...

I would like to know how I add or redirect the page after clicking on submit.

Sorry i'm still learning...

Currently Im using "usebean" to insert the content of the form to the database. I would like to know if how to redirect the page after the enter all info in the fields then click submit..

Thanks

here's the code:

```
<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<html>
    <head><title>CSN Survey</title></head>


<body bgcolor="#ffffff">

 <div>
    <img id="title" src="images/CSN.gif" width="243" height="27" alt="CSN"/>
    <img id="logo" src="images/tr_logo_40.gif" width="178" height="40" alt="tr_logo_40"/>
 </div>
    <hr>
     <h1> insert comment </h1>

<div id="container">

    <form action=""  name="form1" method="POST">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <td><br>Write your comment here:</td>

                 <div id="q1"

                 <td>id:<%=request.getParameter("id")%></td>
                 <td>First name:<textarea name="first_name" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea></td>
                 <td>Last name:<textarea name="last_name" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea></td>
                 <br>
         <br>
                 </div>

                 <td>


                 <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
                 </td>

    </form>
    </div>

                 <jsp:useBean id="survey" class="csnsurveysource.csnsurveyclass" scope="page">
            <jsp:setProperty name="survey" property="*"/>


        </jsp:useBean>

    <% survey.insert();%> 

</body>
</html>
```

**csnsurveyclass.java**:

```
package csnsurveysource;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class csnsurveyclass
{

    private int id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    private Connection connection=null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private Statement st = null;
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test";


    public csnsurveyclass()
    {
         try {
             // Load the database driver
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            // Get a Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "postgres", "qqQQ11!!");
            }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
            }

        }

        public void setid(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getid()
    {
        return (this.id);
    }

    public void setfirst_name(String first_name)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getfirst_name()
    {
        return (this.first_name);
    }
        public void setlast_name(String last_name)
    {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getlast_name()
    {
        return (this.last_name);
    }


    public void insert()
    {

       try
       {
            String sql = "update testing set fname = '"+first_name+"',lname = '"+last_name+"' where id = "+id+"";
            Statement s = connection.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate (sql);
            s.close ();

        }
       catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
                    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be good to use [MVC](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/MVC-detailed.html) pattern,  you can move business logic

```
 survey.insert();
```

into controller and then send redirect

```
response.sendRedirect("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

put where you want to redirect in the action inside your form tag

```
<form action="put here ur action/url"  name="form1" method="POST">
```

Comment: the problem if I do that is, the character that I input in the text field are not forwarded to the DB. the SQL statement in not executed.